# jQuery not working when inside a document ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

I've had this problem for days now and after looking around SO and google I cannot seem to fix it.

I am working offline in WAMP building a website. I am including jQuery in the `<head>` section using the google API's:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It seems all my other jQuery plugins work apart from the ones im trying to build myself.

All my written jQuery is placed in a file called `sitename.js` and in the `/js/` directory like all the other js scripts.

Now the thing is, is that I can't seem to get `$(document).ready(function()` to work, or any click events.

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
      console.log("test");
});
```

When I move the `console.log` outside the document ready function, it displays it in my console (firebug) but when inside, it does not.

Click events do not work either, and I have no idea why:

```
$('.more').live("click",function(){
    console.log("test");
}
```

This does not work either, and I do have a div with the class name of `more`.

I'm not sure what the problem is, whether its incorrect code or another script interfering with this one. Thanks in advance for any suggestions or answers

Comment: Are you loading your script after Jquery?

Comment: Any errors in your console?

Comment: @KevinBowersox The first script I load after the jquery is my main js file which contains my code, its in the footer.

Comment: @j08691 I get these, but not in firebug `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'validate'` `audiokick.js:8
2
Uncaught Error: IndexSizeError: DOM Exception 1 `

Comment: Whatcha mean "but not in firebug"? Have you also tried debugging in Chrome?

Comment: I am in chrome! but I use firebug for chrome, I get those errors on the default `inspect element` tool

Comment: Chrome has its own dev tools; why would you need firebug for it?

Comment: Its what I am used too hah

Comment: Just throwing it out there - but if your scripts are in the footer then you don't need to use $(document).ready().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`live` is not supported any more by jQuery v. 1.9.1

use `.on()` instead:

```
$("#parent").on("click", ".more", function(){
    console.log("test");
});
```

Comment: Thanks! feel stupid haha, fixed the click problem. Will see if the document ready function is working

Comment: @chriz sure, strange issue, I'm still reading again your question to figure out the possible issue related to that one

Comment: @chriz: but your `console.log` didn't work either? How is it related?

Comment: @zerkms when inside a document ready, the console log does not work still

Answer (score 0):

`$` is not defined outside of `$(document).ready` if jQuery is in noconflict mode.

Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){   
  console.log("test");
});
```

Also, make sure you are not linking to http from a https site. These days it's considered best practice to **always** link to the https version of a resource, if available, regardless if from http or https.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Disregard any info you may find about linking without protocol.